# In what instance can a bedroom not have a proper egress window

Tags: building, codes

Wife and I were watching one of the home improvement/ flip  shows.  We noticed that in a bedroom the owner had the big window with the lower sill taken out and only 2 small windows with the sills at about 48" remained in the room.  There was no door to the exterior.

We both commented that they would have to replace the window because of egress code.  In the end the home was done and no new window. Only the 2 small ones in the bedroom.

How is this allowed. Or is it not, as I suspected, and the show was just BS as most of them are?

The home was in Vermont.  Special building codes there?

If this get closed, I'm ok with it, just knew there would be people on here that knew the code for sure.

Comment: Could be weird code.  It was not permitted/inspected.  Windows were bigger than they looked on tv.

Comment: Locally over on the west coast, I think that I wouldn't be allowed to call it a "bedroom." It's an "office," "rec room," etc. The code uses the term "sleeping room" in the emergency escape and rescue opening section. There's no definition listed, so it's down to your choice of dictionary. As long as there isn't a sleeping affordance in there, e.g. a bed, I suspect that it's conformant. A fold out sofa would be an interesting edge case.

Comment: In my locale (SoCal) there is no such requirement that I am aware of except for in special occupancies, such as foster homes and other care home settings, or special conditions, such as basement bedrooms.

Comment: @Jimmy, see [IRC R310.1](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-3-building-planning#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch03_SecR310.1).

Comment: @popham, thanks I see that now So if the room OP is referencing was indeed a sleeping room it would not comply because the bottom of the opening is greater than 44" from the floor (and also perhaps because the opening is too small).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending *precisely wher*e in Vermont, there might not be a building code official to actually inspect it, so it might only come to official attention after it kills someone.

The cities (and ski-area-towns) tend to be pretty loaded with the usual bureaucracy, the smaller towns not so much.

One is supposed to follow applicable codes, but if nobody checks, some people won't.

I live in a small town. I had to have the road crew head decide that my driveway did not need a culvert, I had to submit a zoning application, and I had to have the health department guy look at my septic installation. No other official town input on my building. While this might horrify some, I look at it as "here's your personal responsibility - if the building you put up falls down, that's your problem, so you might want to make sure it doesn't."

This *only* applies to single-family-residential - as far as I recall the State does inspections for commercial work.

Comment: Thank You for the explanation.

Comment: The County I live in allows single family residential construction to declare that you are going to follow code, your title gets flagged, then only septic and electrical inspections are required for a legal build. Even on non-flagged parcels no permit needed for agricultural (barns and sheds).